# Error in plotting of frequency histogram from csv data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I am working with a csv file with pandas module on python3. Csv file consists of 5 columns: job, company's name, description of the job, amount of reviews, location of the job; and i want to plot a frequency histogram , where i pick only the jobs containing the words "mechanical engineer" and find the frequencies of the 5 most frequent locations for the "mechanical engineer" job.

So,i defined a variable engloc which stores all the "mechanical engineer" jobs.

```
engloc=df[df.position.str.contains('mechanical engineer|mechanical engineering', flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)].location
```

and did a histogram plot with matplotlib with code i found online

```
 x = np.random.normal(size = 1000)
 plt.hist(engloc, bins=50)
 plt.gca().set(title='Frequency Histogram ', ylabel='Frequency');
```

but it printed like this

[image]

How can i plot a proper frequency histogram where it plots using only 5 of the most frequent locations for jobs containing "mechanical engineer" words, instead of putting all of the locations in the graph?

This is a sample from the csv file 
[image: csv data screenshot]

Comment: If you share your data somebody may be willing to help you. See [mcve] for a complete explanation.

Comment: Should i include a screenshot of some part or write in the question a few parameters of the data?

Comment: A "representative" sample of data, allowing to plot a meaningful histogram,  entered as text should do. Link to the full data even better.

Comment: Post your data as text, not as a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the following lines should help you with numerical data:

```
import numpy as np
counts_, bins_ = np.histogram(englog.values)
filtered = [(c,b) for (c,b) in zip(counts_,bins_) if counts_>=5]
counts, bins = list(zip(*filtered))
plt.hist(bins[:-1], bins, weights=counts)
```

For a string type try:

```
from collections import Counter 
coords, counts = list(zip(*Counter(englog.values).most_common(5)))
plt.bar(coords, counts)
```

Comment: It gave an error like this "TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''.

Comment: Sadly the second one gave an error too.TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (5 given)

Comment: @Ayano Does this solve your problem? If so you may think about accepting the answer